# ionic cordova paypal plugin and native geocoder compatibility issue

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, plugins

i have installed pay pal cord ova plugin and native Geo coder plugin, native Geo coder plugin stopped pay pal plugin initialization process, 
can anyone help with this.

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: be a little more specific, add a fraction of code, error message you are getting and what have you tried so far. Please refer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask